# create query using hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have  classes: A,B and C

```
A{
B b;
}

B{
C c
}

C{
String str;
}
```

In a class ADao, I wanna execute the following query:

```
Criteria criteria = createCriteria(A.class);
criteria.add(Expression.eq("b.c.str", str));
criteria.setFetchMode("b", FetchMode.EAGER);
criteria.setFetchMode("b.c", FetchMode.EAGER);
```

When I execute this query, I get:

> QueryException: could not resolve property b.c.str

Comment: Can you please post your correct class Structure.

Comment: The classes are too long, but they have the same logic as this prototype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo need explicit joins, with sub-criterias or aliases, as explained in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-associations):

```
Criteria criteria = createCriteria(A.class, "a");
criteria.createAlias("a.b", "b");
criteria.createAlias("b.c", "c");
criteria.add(Expression.eq("c.str", str));
```